# Unable to test Palindrome

Tags: c#

I am trying to convert the text in the console and reverse it to see if it is  a palindrome. If it is, then it will return true and if it is not, then false will be returned. However, I am facing errors since I am new and just started  to learn C#. The error that I get is as follows:

'Palindrome.IsPalindrome(string)': not all code paths return a value

I don't know how to solve this and I dont quite understand it, hence any advice would be very much appreciated. Thank You.

```
using System;

public class Palindrome
{
    public static bool IsPalindrome(string word)
    {

        char[] temp = word.ToCharArray();
        Array.Reverse(temp);
        string emordnilap = new string(temp);

        if(word.Equals(emordnilap)){
            Console.WriteLine("true");

        }else{
            Console.WriteLine("false");
        }

    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Palindrome.IsPalindrome("Deleveled"));
    }

}
```

Comment: `D` character is not equal to `d` character. You should use case-ignoring comparison. All your code can be written in one line: `Console.WriteLine(word.Equals(word.Reverse(),StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)));`

Comment: need to return a value from the method using the return statement

Comment: There is no `return` in `IsPalindrome()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your method is defined as `public static bool IsPalindrome(string word)`

That means it must `return` a boolean (true or false).

You're not actually returning anything, you're just writing it out to the console, and that's what your error is - you're not returning a value.

You need to put `return true;` or `return false;` in your code so that every possible route through the method results in it returning the `bool` you specified in the method signature.

This gives you another issue, because you're doing Console.WriteLine(**_) where _** is the `return` value of your IsPalindrome method. Since you're returning a `bool` then it's strange to write that to the console. It will work, but a better way to do this would be call to the method like this:

```
var isPalindrome = Palindrome.IsPalindrome("Deleveled");

if (isPalindrome == true)
{
   Console.WriteLine("It IS a palindrome!");
}
```

Note that `if (isPalindrome == true)` can be shortened to `if (isPalindrome)`

One of the core aspects of OO programming is SOLID, which are some guidelines for writing code. One of those is the Single Responsibility Principle, which basically means you should try to make bits of your code only do one thing.

So it's better for your IsPalindrome to only do one thing - return true or false if the word is a palindrome - and not do other things such as writing to the console. Leave that for the code that is calling the method.

Just a hint for when your method unexpectedly returns false - `Racecar` is not the same as `racecaR` - you will have to do something about the case. A quick way to do this is with `ToUpper()` to convert your value to upper case before you reverse it and do the comparison.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, after changing the console.WriteLine to returning true and false, it works now. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your method should return a `bool` instead of writing to Console. Try like:

```
public static bool IsPalindrome(string word)
{
        char[] temp = word.ToCharArray();
        Array.Reverse(temp);
        string emordnilap = new string(temp);

        if(word.Equals(emordnilap)){
            return true;    
        }
        else{
           return false;
        }
}
```

Comment: Hrmm... `return word.Equals(emordnilap);` ? upvoted anyway

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I should've returned true or false instead of console. Thank You

Comment: @RomainB. Yes and after changing the return statement i got the output. Thanks

Comment: That would be better indeed

Answer (score 0):

Every path this method can take to get to its end, has to return a boolean value:

```
using System;

public class Palindrome
{
    public static bool IsPalindrome(string word)
    {

        char[] temp = word.ToCharArray();
        Array.Reverse(temp);
        string emordnilap = new string(temp);

        if(word.Equals(emordnilap))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
           return false; 
        }

    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //The ToString() converts your boolean to a string
        Console.WriteLine(Palindrome.IsPalindrome("Deleveled").ToString());
    }

}
```

Try naming your Variables more understandably. That will make your live easier if you get into bigger projects. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/naming-guidelines)